# array from model-class return NULL

Tags: objective-c, macos, model-view-controller

How to call array from the model-class in my `NSWindowController`? The `valueArray` is set in AppDelegate, to the model-class `ValueItem`:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    ValueItem *vi;
    ResultWindowController *rwc;
    IBOutlet NSArrayController *outArrayController;
}
```

and

```
@implementation AppDelegate
....
- (IBAction)pushOk:(NSButton *)sender
{
    self->vi = [[ValueItem alloc]init];
    [vi setValueArray:[outArrayController arrangedObjects]];
    NSLog(@"vi.valueArray is:%@", vi.valueArray);

    if (rwc)
    {
        [rwc close];
    }
    rwc = [[ResultWindowController alloc] init];
    [rwc setShouldCascadeWindows:NO];
    [rwc showWindow:self];

}
```

Calling `NSLog(@"vi.valueArray is:%@", vi.valueArray);` return the arrays content just fine. But when I try to use it in my other `NSWindowController` it return always `NULL`:

```
@interface ResultWindowController : NSWindowController
{
    ValueItem *vi;
    NSNumber *resultAverage;
}
```

and

```
@implementation ResultWindowController
@synthesize resultAverage;
...

- (IBAction)pushChange:(NSButton *)sender
{
    [self calculateAverage];
    [_outputLabel setDoubleValue:[resultAverage doubleValue]];
    NSLog(@"resultAverage is:%@", resultAverage);
    NSLog(@"vi.valueArray is:%@", vi.valueArray);
}

-(void)calculateAverage
{
    resultAverage = [vi.valueArray valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.nomValue"];
}
```

I can't find the missing link? What do I miss here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate and unrelated instances of `ValueItem *vi` in your two classes. That explains why you set it up in the first class, but in the second `vi` is still `nil`.

You should be able to fix it by doing this:

```
rwc = [[ResultWindowController alloc] init];
[rwc setVi:self->vi];                // <--- this
[rwc setShouldCascadeWindows:NO];
[rwc showWindow:self];
```

In order to do that, you should define a proper setter method in `RootWindowController`.

Alternatively, if you want to make your AppDelegate act as a model, you could do:

```
ValueItem *vi = [(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate vi];
```

when you need to access `vi`. You could then remove the `vi` ivar declared in `RootWindowController` (since you would access directly the one in you app delegate).

Actually, it would be better creating a separate class acting as a model. It could be a singleton and you could access it like this:

```
ValueItem *vi = [MyModel sharedModel].vi;
```

far more readable and concise.

Comment: Hello sergio, sorry I'm still new to all that stuff. I just thought with `ValueItem *vi` I just make the model accessible without creating a different one. How can I actually access the same instance of `ValueItem` or do I need some other strategy?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! It works but could you let me know why `[rwc setVi:self->vi];' prevent creating a new and independent from `ValueItem`?

Comment: glad to have helped. unfortunately, I can't understand what you are further asking...

Comment: Sorry my fault. I don't understand how I create the second instance of `ValueItem` in `ResultWIndowsController`? I don't do `[... alloc]init]]` again?

Comment: You would not do that in RootWindowController, rather in your model. Then your model should support multiple values of `vi` (an array?) if you add some more ode of what you are trying to do, it would help...